# how to turn bootstrap cards that are in a row to a slider only on <768px screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some bootstrap cards that are in a row but on small screens i want them to be on a slider instead of one under the other, ie: one card in the middle and left and right buttons.

and i have no idea how to do that.

can i get some help please:

```
<div class="section section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Features Wrapper Start -->
        <div class="features-wrapper row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col" data-aos-delay="200">
                <!-- Single Features Start -->
                <div class="single-feature text-center">
                    <img src="assets/images/icons/massage.png" height="156" alt="feature">
                    <h4 class="title">Mon soin découverte</h4>
                    <p>Massages faciaux tendances ! Bienfaits : circulation sanguine, repulpe zones creuses, liftings naturels ! Essentiel pour peau souple, élastique, anti-rides et anti-âge ! Types dispo dans mon studio à Aix-en-Provence.</p>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Buttons">
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Lire plus</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Single Features End -->
            </div>
            <div class="col active" data-aos-delay="400">
                <!-- Single Features Start -->
                <div class="single-feature text-center">
                    <img src="assets/images/icons/delux.png" height="156" alt="feature">
                    <h4 class="title">Mes soins signatures®️</h4>
                    <p>J'ai conçu deux protocoles de soins visage pour les femmes, répondant aux attentes en traitant à la fois l'aspect physique et psychologique du visage. Obtenez des résultats durables et visibles à l'intérieur et à l'extérieur. Mes soins signatures s'adaptent à votre unicité.</p>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Buttons">
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Lire plus</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Single Features End -->
            </div>
            <div class="col"  data-aos-delay="600">
                <!-- Single Features Start -->
                <div class="single-feature text-center">
                    <img src="assets/images/icons/body-massage.png" height="156" alt="feature">
                    <h4 class="title">Mon soin corps</h4>
                    <p>Technicienne Spa Bien-être RNCP je vous propose des massages corps essentielle pour rééquilibrer votre énergie laissez vous tenter parmis le massage MOI (massage des organes internes), un drainage lymphatique ou un massage intuitif holistique. </p>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Buttons">
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Lire plus</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Single Features End -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Features Wrapper End -->
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    /*this is for the cards*/

    const colorsDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.features-wrapper, .packages-wrapper');
    
    colorsDiv.forEach(function (elem) {
    
        const children = [...elem.children];
    
        children.forEach((el) => {
            el.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
                children.forEach((btn) => {
                    btn.classList.remove('active');
                })
                e.target.classList.add('active');
            });
        });
    })
    </script>
<!-- Feature End -->
```

My idea to make this initialy was to make a from the start a separate slider with the cards and do it

```
display : none
```

then on the small screens i switch it to

```
display : block
```

and the original to

```
display : none
```

Comment: Sounds like `css media query` will help you

Comment: yes absolutly, but the thing is how to change the row into a slider

Comment: I would change the container `display` to a flex-box only for that media query. Then check the horizontal `overflow`.